# Delay with other functions

Tags: delay

Basic Task:
A Switching progress should be delayed for a specific time after starting it through a button.
It doesn`t matter how long the button is pressed or how long the finger is on the button.
After the switch-on relay has expired, a new press on a button should set the switching progress back.

Addition:
After starting the software, the delay-time should be adjustable in 3 stages, with a repeating pressing of a button.
Requirement for this is, that the setting of the stages need to have a prederterminded interval.
So that it can be elevated and lowered with consecutively pressing of a button (1-2-3-2-1...).
Every stage is displayed via LED.

I'm sorry for my bad english, but i hope some of you guys could help me with it and find a solution for me :)

I give my thanks

I'm a beginner, so i don't know.
I know it has to include a delay, so i would expect to put time.sleep(x) in there. But otherwise i'm lost :/